# Does ARIMA require normally distributed data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, arima, normality-assumption

I want forecast inflation using ARIMA model. My questions are:

1. Does ARIMA require normally distributed input data? (Because my data—inflation—is not normal.)
2. If ARIMA require normally distributed input data, how can I transform it to be normal? My data (inflation) contains negative values so I couldn't use the log transform to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

NO. The errors resulting from the ARIMA model must be normally distributed.

Comment: Please add the following caveat "for parametric tests of sufficiency( t values for the coefficients)  and necessity (randomness of the residuals) to be valid"

Comment: I would be a bit more careful.  It is usually easiest when the errors are normal, but the ARIMA model may still be estimated consistently when they are not. http://math.unice.fr/~frapetti/CorsoP/Chapitre_4_IMEA_1.pdf

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, nice lecture notes under the link!